# ubuntu 17.04 cant repeat login screen trying to login to gnome but can login lubuntu environent

Tags: 16.04, 17.04, lightdm, gdm

I installed ubuntu 17.04 from 16.04 and restarted. Afterwards I got the low graphics mode screen. After some playing around I was able to get a graphical login screen (low res) but when trying to login it would just return me to the login screen again. After trying changing the environment to Lubuntu I am able to login but I havent been able to get the gnome environment working. can anyone help ?